# In jenkins pipeline For failed jobs email should indicate the stage at which pipeline failed with link to job failure?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I need to notify the users in for the failed job in jenkins pipeline, the email should indicate the stage at which pipeline failed with the job link of which is failed?

can anyone help how to do this?

Comment: What is your configuration currently? Which plugins are you using for that?